# Solution for changing' img id' with 'document.getElementById' when selecting from auto generated list

Tags: javascript, php

Solution for changing image id when selecting from auto generated list
This code: 
    `<?php foreach(glob('pano/*.png') as $filename):?>
                    <li><a href="javascript:chgpano()"><?php $path_parts = pathinfo ($filename); echo $path_parts['filename'], "\n";?></a> </li>
                 <?php endforeach; unset( $filename);?>`

Generates a screen with a button for each of the files. The function chgpano:

```
function chgpano()
{
ima = document.getElementById("tonto");
init();
}
```

Changes the img Id assigned to variable "ima". The contents of "tonto" need to reflect the image selected.

**The following cannot work, but does show the intent:**

```
  function chgpano()
{
    img id="tonto" src= ('pano/'+ variable with text from button selected)
ima = document.getElementById("tonto");
init();
}
```

I saw a similar question but it was rejected as being unclear

Comment: id is meant to be for one element in html. you should use class for that or the new tag 'data-id' for example... but anyway ... your codes contain to many errors... if you explain exactly what you wanna do i could write u a simple example.so why do you wanna changethe element's identification to ima?

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned in the comment the purpose of id in html is for one single element..
so i would use `class` or the new `data-TAG`.

to reuse the php script also for other scripts/sites i would scan the folder and convert everything to `json`.(simple array containing all the paths of the png's)

here is a example using javascript 1.7 (modern html5 browsers)

to handle multiple elements with one handler.

scanForPNGs.php

```
echo json_decode(glob('pano/*.png'));
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<style>
 img{width:100px;}
 img.IMA{opacity:0.3;}
</style>
<script>
var box;
function ajax(a,b,c){c=new XMLHttpRequest;c.open('GET',a);c.onload=b;c.send()};
function display(){
 box.innerHTML='<img src="'+JSON.parse(this.response).join('"><img src="')+'">';
}
function whatever(e){
 e.target.classList.toggle('IMA');// activate & deactivate
 //or
 //e.target.dataset['IMA']=e.target.dataset['IMA']=='ON'?'OFF':'ON';
}
window.onload=function(){
 box=document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
 box.addEventListener('click',whatever,false);
 ajax('scanForPNGs.php',display);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

inside the `whatever` function you can add whatever proprieties or functions to the element that you click.

in my case i just change the opacity.

the trigger is the image itself.

i did not test this code...to be sure test it with chrome.

example

http://jsfiddle.net/8jeDS/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// PHP can look like
$liA = '';
foreach(glob('pano/*.png') as $f){
  $path_parts = pathinfo($f);
  $liA .= "<li><a href='javascript:chgpano($f)'>{$path_parts['filename']}></a></li>";
}
echo $liA;

// JavaScript can look like + some goodies
var doc = document; // get in the habit of declaring variables
function E(e){
  return doc.getElementById(e);
}
var tonto = E('tonto');
function chgpano(f){
  tonto.src = f;
}
```

I would use external JavaScript, putting the `<script>` tag at the bottom of the body. Alternatively, you would put the `<script>` tag in the `<head>` and run `onload`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys & Gals. This fixed it:

```
<?php
            foreach(glob('pano/*.png') as $filename):$path_parts = pathinfo ($filename); $id_front = $path_parts['filename'];?>
                <li> <a onclick = "javascript:chgpano('<?php echo $id_front ?>')"><?php  echo $id_front, "\n";?></a><img id= <?php echo $id_front ?> src= <?php echo$filename ?> style="display:none"></li>
             <?php endforeach; unset( $filename);?>
```

As you can see I put the same variable being used to assign the image id into the function parameter.

Now the variable **ima** contains the img id

```
function chgpano(blah)
{
ima = document.getElementById(blah);
init();
}
```

I had to move the variable difinition out side the

div otherwise the function parameter was getting filled before the variable was defined.

Comment: I tried to vote this up so that the question would no longer be listed as unanswered. But I cannot vote up my own responses. So please someone else.